# Trying to build a source rpm getting: error: Architecture is not included: x86_64

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

When I try to build a [source rpm for `podman` 4.5](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=2186589) on Alma Linux 8, I'm getting

```
rpmbuild --rebuild ./podman-4.5.0-1.fc39.src.rpm 
Installing ./podman-4.5.0-1.fc39.src.rpm
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mock does not exist - using root
...
error: Architecture is not included: x86_64
```

How do I solve the problem of

> error: Architecture is not included: x86_64

If I run

```
rpm -ivh ./podman-4.5.0-1.fc39.src.rpm
```

I can jump into `~/rpmbuild/SPECS` and get this same error with

```
rpmbuild -bp podman.spec 
error: Architecture is not included: x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the macros behind the spec file with

```
rpmspec -P ./podman.spec
```

If you see something like

```
Name: podman
Epoch: 5
Version: 4.5.0
License: Apache-2.0 and BSD-2-Clause and BSD-3-Clause and ISC and MIT and MPL-2.0
Release: 1.el8
ExclusiveArch: %{golang_arches_future}
...
```

Or any macro which starts with a `%` like  `%{golang_arches_future}` that's a sign of the problem: the macro isn't being expanded.

---

In this case, it seems the underlying problem is that [the RPM macro `%go_arches` was renamed to `%golang_arches_future` 9 months ago](https://pagure.io/go-rpm-macros/pull-request/48). Subsequently new packages of podman are using the new variable in the Fedora Rawhide repo. You can revert that change in the spec and go back to using `%go_arches`, or you can just set the new macro in runtime as an argument to `rpmbuild` for the architecture you need to support.

```
rpmbuild -D "%golang_arches_future x86_64" -bb ./podman.spec
```